# Show alert in Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) bot with [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I want to show an alert like this pic: 
 
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was [Oforwarded](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/542908) to the user group of `python-telegram-bot` and has essentially been answered there:

Passing the `text` parameter (and optionally `show_alert=True`) to [`answerCallbackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) will result the text being prompted to the user.
In `python-telegram-bot`, this can conveniently be done via the [`CallbackQuery.answer`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery.answer) shortcut.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Yeah, when using `show_alert=True` the alert happens like a popup and, the user must click the `OK` button so I just pass the `text` and happen what I want. `update.callback_query.answer('First Page!')`